# Python generator and file object

Tags: python

I have a question about generator and file object.

If I write code

```
def iter(ls):
    count=0
    for k in ls:
        if count==2:
            break
        count+=1
    for k in ls:
        yield k

test=[1,2,3,4]

k=iter(test)
for i in k:
    print i
```

Then the output is

> 1 2 3 4

Yes, I can understand this because the break statement in this code does not affect the following yield statement.

But if I do similar thing with file, in this case, I make a "data" file and it's written

```
1
2
3
4
```

and If I only change the line

```
test=[1,2,3,4]  →  test=open("data","r")
```

Then the result is

> 4

This means that the break statement affects somehow, so the genetor made in for loop contaning "yield" is different from that of previous case.

What's the reason for this difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, because the file object also stores where it has currently read upto. So when you try to iterate over the file object again (without doing `.seek()` ) , it will start from the next line (where you left off) . That is after openning a file, and iterating over it once, if you try to iterate over it again (without doing `.seek()`), it does not yield any result since in the first iteration itself the cursor is at the end of file and there is nothing else to read. Example -

My a.txt -

```
1
2
3
4
```

Code -

```
>>> for i in f:
...     print(i)
...
1

2

3

4
>>> for i in f:
...     print(i)
...
>>>
```

--

As indicated above, if you want to move the file cursor to the start of the file, you will have to use `file.seek(0)` , 0 indicating to move the the starting position.